# Mount Windows share via CIFS in CentOS not working (but smbclient does)

Tags: centos, samba, mount, openvz, cifs

I'm a bit frustrated...I'm trying to mount a windows share via CIFS in CentOS 6.3, but it's not working:

```
mount -v -t cifs -o credentials=/data/conf/credentials/fileserver //10.0.1.200/projects   /mnt/fileserver/projects
```

Which gives me this:

```
Unable to apply new capability set.
```

No idea why, because connecting with smbclient works fine:

```
smbclient //10.0.1.200/projects -A /data/conf/credentials/fileserver
```

Any knows what the reason could be?

Comment: Are you running the `mount` command as root? Is SElinux enabled?

Comment: Yes, running as root, no SElinux. But apparently I can't mount CIFS in an OpenVZ container...which explains why I couldn't find anything explaining the error message ;) I added my workaround as an answer, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I figured it out. Problem was that I was running CentOS in an OpenVZ Container, where apparently CIFS doesn't seem to be virtualized - at least according to this source:

http://www.linux-faqs.info/virtualization/mount-samba-share-inside-an-openvz-container

It contains a nice workaround though and I ended up creating the mount on the host machine and mounting it with --bind in the guest.